# Using Netlify to deploying Python Script written in Node JS

Tags: python, node.js, netlify

I wish to deploy my node js application on Netlify, inside which I have called a python script.

I have used netlify functions to deploy my node js application. While other endpoints work perfectly fine.
I am not able to execute the endpoint which calls the python script. It crashes with Error - spawn python ENOENT
I have used 2 methods to run python script 1. using child_process 2. using python-shell , both run on my local , but i am not able to deploy it over netlify, I get the following error message
[image]
Following is my github repo link

https://github.com/erAnusriM/nodejs_python

my python.js file which calls the script

```
const express = require("express");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const cors = require("cors");
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  })
);

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/script", (req, res) => {
  var dataToSend;
  var childPython = spawn("python", ["script1.py"]);

  childPython.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
    dataToSend = data.toString();
  });
  childPython.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    res.send(dataToSend);
  });

  // res.json({ hello: "hi" });
});

router.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ hello: "hi" });
});

app.use("/.netlify/functions/python", router);

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

I tried implementing the script on node js and it is working on my local. But it does not deploy on Netlify.

Is netlify the correct platform to deploy a python script?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Netlify doesn't support languages other than JS/TS/Go